# WP7 Google's Admob sdk load/refresh causing to lose focus from a textbox

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, admob

I am trying to use the recently released Google's Admob sdk for a Windows Phone 7 app. The problem is there is a textbox in the page and whenever Admob's ad is loaded or refreshed, the focus is lost from the textbox causing the input keyboard to hide (kind of unintentional). Does anyone else have a similar problem? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

the AdMob SDK is currently only in BETA, i would either wait for a full release if it's inhibiting your programs function or make do with it until then